# Запятая при обороте "как на чудика"

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

А я снова о сравнительном обороте. "Парни посмотрели на Дмитрия как на чудика". Здесь же запятая не ставится, потому что сравнительный оборот тесно связан со сказуемым, иными словами, образует смысловой центр. Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Парни посмотрели на Дмитрия как на чудика.**

Если принимать формальное решение, соответствующее правилам, то оно однозначно: **запятая не нужна,**  смотреть как на чудика ― это считать чудиком. И главное ― никто эту запятую не ставит.

И всё-таки сомнения у меня есть. Смотреть как на чудака ― это переносное значение, здесь нет значения прямого: посмотреть ―  взглянуть.

А в заданном предложении это был именно реальный взгляд, и пауза здесь возможна: **Парни посмотрели на Дмитрия (так),  как (смотрят) на чудика.**

Однако эти рассуждения вряд ли кто примет во внимание:  **во всех примерах, где смотрят или посмотрели, запятая отсутствует.**

**Примеры:**

― На меня посмотрели **как на больного**. Сочувственно и с сожалением. [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]

На него все посмотрели **как на идиота.** [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

Казалось бы Оттого, что она так искренно удивилась его словам и смотрела на него **как на чудака**, он смутился. [А. П. Чехов. В овраге (1900)]

Штабные придурки, когда я к ним являлся, смотрели на меня **как на чудака**, мешающего их занятиям, и везде меня морили по два-три дня. [С. М. Голицын. Записки беспогонника (1946-1976)]

На гостя, который страстно отстаивает свою точку зрения за обеденным столом, в лучшем случае посмотрят **как на чудака-эксцентрика**, а в худшем ― как на человека плохо воспитанного. [Всеволод Овчинников. Корни дуба. Впечатления и размышления об Англии и англичанах (1974-1978) // «Новый мир», 1979]

Comment: То есть, тут пиши как считаешь нужным?

Comment: Запятую желательно не ставить: ее в лучшем случае сочтут авторским знаком, а в худшем - посчитают за ошибку. Но если распространить оборот, шансы на постановку запятой повышаются: Парни посмотрели на Дмитрия,  как (смотрят) на непонятного чудика.